# How to have javascript code on a different file then html?

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext

I am constructing a calculator and this is my html for the calculator
HTML

```
      <div id=”calculator”>
        <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled>
        <div class="first-row">
          <input type="button" name="operator" value="+" action="add">
          <input type="button" name="operator" value="-" action="subtract">
          <input type="button" name="operator" value="*" action="multiple">
          <input type="button" name="operator" value="/" action="divide">
        </div>
        <div class="second-row">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="7">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="8">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="9">
        </div>
        <div class="third-row">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="4">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="5">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="6">
        </div>
        <div class="fourth-row">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="1">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="2">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="3">
        </div>
        <div class="fifth-row">
          <input type="button" class="number" value="0" onclick="numberPress('0')">
          <input type="button" class="operator" value="=">
        </div>
      </div>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/calculator.js"></script>
```

So in my javascript code, it checks if the button clicked is a operator, then if it is, then it prints out "operator" in the console.

Javascript

```
    const calculator = document.getElementById("calculator")
    calculator.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("input")) {
            key = e.target
            name = e.target.name
            if(name == "operator") {
                console.log("operator")     
            }
        }
    })
```

The problem is that for the first line, it does not find the calculator id and it stores null in calculator. So, I tried putting the javascript in the same file, but still it does not work.
Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You are not using this character `"`

You are using this character `”`

So you are writing `”calculator”` instead of `"calculator"` in your HTML

You must use ***plain*** quote marks in HTML

Comment: @YLim - Describe "it doesn't work" which doesn't tell us anything. I took your HTML and Javascript from your question, but then in a `.html` and a `.js` file, then I _fixed your quote marks_ just like "edu" said here — and it worked. I click any of the "operator" buttons and it prints to the console.

Comment: You're welcome! I created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hgz9pe7b/3/ where the value of `document.getElementById("calculator")` is printed to a div below the calculator (since it's an object you won't see much, but it's not null)

Comment: @StephenP  it says that "TypeError: calculator is null" when I run the html. Also, when I ran the code in CodePen, it worked too. But, when I ran in sublime, it did not giving me a error.

Comment: @YLim — once again … check the _quote marks_ that you are using. In your question your `<div id=”calculator”>` is using the Unicode `right double quotation mark` character 0x201D (using the _right_ quote on both the right and left) — In HTML you _must_ use the **plain** quote marks `"` Unicode `quotation mark` character 0x0022 which is what you are using _everywhere else_. `<div class="first-row">` is using the plain quote. `type="button"` uses the plain quote. It is _**only**_ on `id=”calculator”` that you're using the wrong quote marks, and that prevents your `getElementById` from working.